# How to pass a string to AjaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadComplete or OnClientUploadError

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I am using the AjaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload and wondering if there is a way to pass an status message back with the call back.

OnClientUploadComplete

OnClientUploadError

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send some value from code behind to be accessed in javascript, may be you can have label and pass the value to the label like below

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "size", "top.$get(\"" + lblUploadStatus.ClientID + "\").innerHTML = 'There was an Error Processing the Request : Error " + ex.Message.ToString()  + "';", true);
```

You can hide the label using css if you donot want user to see the message or you can use a hidden text box.

there is simple example here http://technico.qnownow.com/using-asyncfileupload-control-in-asp-net-ajax/